Get class properties from datagrid ItemSources
How can i get all properties of class that is an ItemSource of DataGrid.
I have some classes that I assign as item sources to the DataGrid control.
I want to access the properties of the class that I assigned as itemssource in the Preview Key Down event.
Since the class name is variable, I am trying to create a common method. Similar to the one below.
private void DataGrid_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    DataGrid grid = sender as DataGrid;
    var dataSource = grid.ItemsSource;
    foreach (var prop in dataSource.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        
    }
}


@Clemens
This method will not always work. Please see the example at this link: https://onlinegdb.com/FzKL2qudG

@Clemens It gives me null.

@Gokhan
In general, any IEnumerable can be passed to ItemsSource. I would advise getting the first element of the collection and determining the type by it. As far as I know, DataGrid column autogeneration also works this way.

@EldHasp thanx for attention.  how can i get first element from dataSource. i tried "var element=dataSource[0]" but it is not work.

Sorry, GetElementType only works for arrays. You may use LINQ like dataSource.Cast<object>().FirstOrDefault()?.GetType();


how can i get first element from dataSource.

Example: https://onlinegdb.com/O8QmfeIAa
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class HelloWorld {
  static void Main() {
    IEnumerable coll = new List<string>() {"first", "second"};
    object item = coll.Cast<object>().First();
    Type itemType = item.GetType();
    foreach (var prop in itemType.GetProperties())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(prop.Name);
    }
  }
}

P.S. But if the collection is empty, then you will have to track its filling and only after adding an element determine its type.

It perfectly works. Thanks.
